# Настроить DS в BIND (named)

Tags: linux, centos, dns, bind

Здравствуйте!
Использую `BIND 9`.

Допустим, у меня есть зона `test.ru` подписанная `DNSSEC`, работает правильно, всё ок. Я создаю ещё одну зону `hello.test.ru` (То есть формально я регистратор этой зоны) и подписываю её так же как и первую.

Теперь, как когда-то я передал `DS`-ключ регистратору `ru`, я должен передать `DS` ключ куда-то себе, как бы глупо это не звучало, но я не знаю куда.

**Вопрос:** В какой конфиг вписать этот ключ?

**P.S:** вопрос навеян [этим](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/troubleshooting#step1)

Все мои саб-домены с недавних пор помечены как `untrusted/insecure`